# Check whether a word document in a Document Library has a portrait or landscape orientation

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-rest-api, wopi

I have an aspx page where I need to render a preview of certain word documents that are stored in a document library. 
The preview is being retrieved via rest API and displayed inside an iframe, but I need the height and width of the iframe to be dynamic according to the orientation of the word document (it can be "portrait" or "landscape"). Does anyone have a solution regarding how to check the orientation of word documents in a Document Library? Am I completely off the track in dealing with this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: Is this being done in a custom VS solution?

Comment: Nope, I am just referencing javascript and jQuery libraries to an aspx page made with vs code. In my custom.js file I am using rest API to retrieve documents from the document library.